# Brownie: Is it safe to store actual private key?

Tags: private-key, brownie, trustwallet

My question is, is it completely safe to create an account with real funds in Brownie without hardware wallet, only with a password? Is there a possibility the private key stored like that could be compromised somehow? And where does it stored on the computer?

In addition I have an issue: I use Trust Wallet installed on an empty smartphone as the main wallet with actual funds. As it does not allow to get the private key directly, I created a local account in Brownie from a seed phrase (for a new test Trust Wallet account), printed a private key in the console and thus created an account - is it a safe way, or is there another better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keystore files are encrypted JSON files stored in your local machine. You can access them in `~/.brownie/accounts` on Linux/MAC OS (`C:\Users\<User>\Appdata/Roaming/brownie/accounts` on Windows). These files are encrypted using `aes-128-ctr`. (use give a password to encrypt your private key). You can find more information regarding them [here](https://julien-maffre.medium.com/what-is-an-ethereum-keystore-file-86c8c5917b97).

If you look at this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55014/how-insecure-is-aes-128-ctr-to-encrypt-any-kind-of-data-using-the-ethereum-keyst) question, which is regarding the security of `aes-128-ctr`, you will see that the security of encrypted `json` files depends on the passwrod you use.

> Even if thus the key might be about 80-bit good, which is not entirely
> unbreakable by brute force but still quite secure.